# How to solve a differential equation problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I want to find the solution of the following differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+y^m=1.$$
For example, if $m=1$, then $y=1-e^{-x}.$
If $m=2$, we have $y=\tanh(x)$, but for $m\ge 3$, $y=?$.

Comment: Is there any initial condition? In both the examples you solve you implicitly assume that $y(0)=0$.

Comment: You get $x$ as a function of $y$ viz. $\int dx=\int\frac{dy}{1-y^m}$. If you factorise $1-y^m$ over $\Bbb R$ using its roots in $\Bbb C$, the rest is an exercise in partial fractions.

Comment: Yes, we assume y(0)=0.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $dx =\frac{1}{1-y^m}dy$, so $x=\int \frac{1}{1-y^m}dy$, which has no elementary representations. (Can still be expressed in terms of hypergemoetric or incomplete beta, but I don't think that was what you were looking for.)